# Recommended client to handle more than one SIP account?

Tags: windows, voip, sip

I currently have two SIP accounts, so [Counterpath](http://www.counterpath.com/communicator-suite.html)'s XLite won't do, as it only handles one. They have a commercial version (Bria, eyeBeam : Not sure of the difference).

Before I buy either Bria or eyeBeam, I'd like to check if this is the only good SIP client for Windows that can handle more than one SIP account at a time, or if there are other options I should know about.

Answer (score 3):

[Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) (multi-platform) supports multiple SIP accounts as well as audio, video, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think [Gizmo](http://gizmo5.com/pc/download/) can handle multiple SIP accounts.

I know [Fring](http://www.fring.com/default.asp) does multiple SIP accounts, but that's only on your mobile though.

Otherwise, [here's a comprehensive list of SIP software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software).

Comment: Thanks for the links. It looks like Gizmo is primarily meant to be used for their commercial SIP offer, but maybe it can be used as a free SIP client.

Answer (score 1):

[3CX Phone](http://www.3cx.com/VOIP/voip-phone.html) is good SIP client which can handle several accounts.

Edit: Phonebook sucks - no search, no saving dialed numbers, ... :(

Comment: Good for what? What does it do? Are you affiliated with them?

Comment: See my edit. No I am not affiliated.